# PIC Alternate Pin Function for PWM

Tags: pic, pwm, programming

I am using a PIC12F1571 which have 3 PWM pins and two alternate PWM pins. What I want to achieve is to use the 3 original PWM pins and the switch to an alternate pin in software in order to get a 4th PWN pin. I am only partly successful since I am able to write to the 4th PWM but at the same time the original PWM is written to out of my control. It is obvious that I am doing something wrong or it may not be possible.

The thing is I don't need the PWM that I switch from at the time, its is idle and won't be active again until I have switched back. The data sheet allows two PWM pins to be switched to alternate pins. The idea is to have individual PWM signals to four different LEDs of which none will be active at the same time.

My question is if anyone know if it is possible to switch to alternate pin controlled by software using the PIC12F1571? The data sheet does not give a clue on this.

Comment: maybe an external multiplexer?

Comment: Mike, I am not familiar with external multiplexers. Can you give me a hint on where/how to get more information, please?

Comment: ask google. e.g. MAX4310 family

Comment: Thank you Mike, I will Google and study the subject!

Answer (score 0):

If it could do PWM on four channels they would brag about it in the datasheet, it's a selling point. As it stands, it has three channels of PWM. When you try to move a PWM channel from one pin to another, the other pin would not be a PWM anymore.

Section 11.1 in the datasheet:

> the following functions can be *moved* between different pins.

If you want a fourth PWM channel you have to modulate it by software using one of the timers. Sometimes the USART can be put to clever use here, loading the serial shift register with a bit pattern such as `11100000` and selecting a high enough baud rate.

Comment: MANY thanks for your quick response!! The thing is I don't need the PWM that I switch from at the time, its is idle and won't be active again until I have switched back. The data sheet allows two PWM pins to be switched to alternate pins. The idea is to have individual PWM signals to four different LEDs of which none will be active at the same time. It seems easier to find another PIC than to produce my own PWM.

Comment: @GoranF Ok, that makes the question a bit more clear. Could you please update the question with this information? I have a feeling it's possible to solve.

Comment: I have updated my original question, thanks pipe for the suggestion!